# service worker registration failed with: DOMException

Tags: angular, service, progressive-web-apps, worker, domexception

> service worker registration failed with: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8082/') with script ('http://localhost:8082/ngsw-worker.js'): Operation has been aborted

I was trying with angular monorepo pwa and getting the same issue with angular pwa.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.